# Flutter - Change checkmark (tick) with other icon in checkbox

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox, radio-button

What I want to achieve is checkbox functionality (multiple selections with a Select All button) with radio buttons.
As an alternative, I am trying to change the check (tick) icon with a dot (as in a radio button). Is it possible? If yes, how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You may find this link useful

https://github.com/Dhanraj-FlutterDev/flutter_custom_checkbox/blob/master/lib/custom_checkbox.dart

The author demonstrates how to customise a checkbox.

For example, this would create a checkbox that looks similar to a radio button

```
    class CustomCheckbox extends StatefulWidget {
      const CustomCheckbox({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<CustomCheckbox> createState() => _CustomCheckboxState();
    }
    
    class _CustomCheckboxState extends State<CustomCheckbox> {
      bool isChecked = false;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() => isChecked = !isChecked);
          },
          child: AnimatedContainer(
              height: 28,
              width: 28,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1.0), border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
              child: isChecked ? const Icon(Icons.adjust) : null),
        );
      }
    }
```